# How can I convert this while loop to a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

First of all I want to tell you that I am currently learning javascript, and I have run into a problem.
I have tried most of the methods I have learned so far and could not do it. If someone could tell me how it works I would appreciate it.

This is the while loop I can't pass it to a for loop

```js
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

let currentCard;

while (currentCard != 'spade') {
   currentCard = cards[Math.floor (Math.random () * 4)];
   console.log(currentCard);
}
```

I really wish I could understand how to take this while loop to a for loop

Comment: What does "pass it to a for loop" mean?

Comment: `for(initialise;condition;final-expression)` - just identify which parts of your code are the parts of the for loop

Comment: @CertainPerformance then how will the code ever pick many cards, the last of which is a spade? Following your logic, you don't need `cards` at all, you just need `const currentCard = 'spade';`

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is kinda cheating, buy hey, this isn't wrong :-)

```js
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

let currentCard;

for (;currentCard!='spade';) {
  currentCard = cards [Math.floor (Math.random () * 4)];
  console.log (currentCard);
}
```

Comment: why not put `let currentCard` as the initialise statement - no point in it being visible outside the loop, you know it will always end up being `spade` after the loop :p ...

Comment: @JaromandaX no reason, just doing minimum changes to convert it into a "for" loop.

Comment: I wasn't really serous, TBH. Of course its better to move the variable into initialize statement.

Comment: To be perfectly frank, a do-while loop is a better fit for the logic anyway :p - maybe not ... the scope is wrong ... for loop wins :p

Comment: @JaromandaX agreed, And hey, at least i didn't put console.log in the post statement, like this :-D ... for (let currentCard;currentCard!='spade'; console.log(currentCard)) currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];

Comment: that's exactly where I'd have put it :p

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Hi, thanks you  all for the help, but I can't understand why this final expression is not written
and when I write this final expression `for (;currentCard!='spade'; currentCard++)` in the code it results in an infinite block, Could you tell me why this happens?

Comment: Why would you do currentCard++ here? You get a random card out of 4, why would you increment it at any point?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Really excuse me if I'm wrong, but that was necessary to increase the value of the index of the strings? 0 = diamond 1 = spade etc, wasn't that what makes the names change? and that's why I don't understand why it doesn't put the currentCard ++.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the selection random? Or just iterate through all the cards. In the former case, nope, there is no reason to increment the index.